# Electron: httpReferrer in loadURL doesn't set referrer of the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, electron

I'm trying to set the window's referrer for the URL requests.
Right now when I sent a request, the "referer" header in it is blank and I need it to contain any distinguishable info so the server-side can whitelist it for me. They won't whitelist an empty referer though.

The "referer" header can't be set directly in the request since it's unsafe.
So I'm trying to set it on the electron side.

Current code:

```
function createWindow(): void {
    
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    height: 1024,
    width: 1280,
    webPreferences: {
      webSecurity: false,
      devTools: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? false : true
    }
  });

  mainWindow.loadURL(
    url.format({
      pathname: path.join(__dirname, './index.html'),
      protocol: 'file:',
      slashes: true
    }), {
      httpReferrer: {
        url: 'http://localhost:3000',
        policy: 'origin',
      },
    }
  );
};

app.on('ready', createWindow);
```

(http://localhost:3000 - could be replaced with anything else)

But the referer in the requests from this window is still empty.

How do I set the windows referrer for the requests in electron?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's impossible to send a "fake" referrer. It will be empty anyway. I had to make a workaround by sending info in the another parameter